# How to implement actionbar activities in android <3

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an actionbar in the API 10. I've created the layout file as 'actionbar.xml' which is included as a layout on every screen. I have a clickable image view on the actionbar layout. How do I write an 'onClick()' method for this. Meaning, do I have to write this method in every activity? Is there anyway I can create a separate activity as 'ActiobarActivity.java' which will have 'onClick()'? If so, then how do I link it to the flow of the application as it is there on every screen?

Basically, can anyone suggest an approach to implement a clickable widget on actionbar in API < 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is what Actionbar Sherlock is for:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to android. In fact I've been introduced to this hardly a couple of weeks ago. Could you please to tell me how to use this in my code?

Comment: No I can't because it's too much to share only in a comment or even a question on stackoverflow.  There is documentation of their site that will do a better job than I can repeating it here.  Actionbar Sherlock, unfortunately is not that easy to use, the project setup is somewhat challenging.  And how its setup has some ramifications you should be aware of.  Primarily you have to compile against API 14 (4.0).  That means you have to be careful to not use anything from a higher API level than what you plan to ship with.  It works, but you have to be aware of what you're doing.

Comment: Actionbar Sherlock is a fantastic library, and it works, but its something for an intermediate to advanced Android developer.  The samples are included, and you can easily view them on github.  https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples/demos If it becomes to much for you hire me as I've done this many times.

Comment: Ha! okay. Let me try for a while first. Anyway is there some alternate approach to have something like action bar then?

Comment: Download the APKs and install them using adb.  Try them out and see what all Actionbar Sherlock can do and how much you need to use of it.

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarSherlock at http://actionbarsherlock.com is an Android library for implementing the action bar design pattern using the native ActionBar on 3.0+ and a third-party library on pre-3.0.

Other ActionBar implementations for pre-3.0 devices:

GreenDroid at https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

or android-actionbar at https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar